# Unable to ssh via phoenix / Elixir

Tags: ssh, erlang, elixir, elixir-iex

I want to ssh to a remote host via a phoenix app.

I am using Erlang :ssh following these steps

1) Starting an iex Session

```
iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

2) Ensuring that :ssh application has started

```
:application.ensure_all_started(:ssh)
```

3) ssh to remote server

```
{:ok, conn} = :ssh.connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 22, [user: 'root', user_dir: 'priv/keys', silently_accept_hosts: true])
```

I am asked for ssh password even after following all these information.

**I have the IP and the user values correctly passed also the key in priv/keys folder.**

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your key file has a passphrase, you will need to include one of the `*_pass_phrase` options.

```
{:ok, conn} = 
  :ssh.connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 22, 
    [user: 'root', user_dir: 'priv/keys', silently_accept_hosts: true,
    rsa_pass_phrase: 'mypassphrase'])
```